# I published my private SSH key in a repository

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

This may be the most stupid question in this forum. But I just created a private repository and somehow my public and private ssh key were written into files inside the local repo.

When I published my repo to bitbucket the files with both of my SSH Keys got published, too. So now they are openly accessable on my repo. And even when I delete them you find them in the log files. How can I safely return from that mistake?

Comment: Ok, I deleted my SSH Keys and replaced it on each account. But I am not able to delete my history in Bitbucket. I followed GitHubs Guide but they still show up in the deleted files.

Answer (score 6):

**Your private key is compromised. You must replace it everywhere you used it before, immediately.**

1. Generate a new private and public key pair, *right now*.
2. Remove the public key from the list of allowed keys *everywhere* you used it.
   Replace it with the new public key.
3. Remove the old private key from the history of the repository.
   You can follow [GitHub's guide](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/).
4. Remove the old private key, you don't need it anymore.

You'll need to figure out how the key ended up in the repo.
To avoid further mistakes,
and your new key showing up again in that repo,
I suggest to remove the repo from the internet while you investigate.
You can easily push it back later when you're done.

Comment: *I* can't make the edit to put your first two sentences in heading case.  I feel like they could use it to really illustrate the sheer urgency in this matter.

Comment: Thank you. I am just doing all of that what is a real pain. But I get the urgency.

Answer (score 5):

There is no "return" - that private key is now compromised.
 Delete your private key from `~/.ssh`, and generate yourself a new one (with `ssh-keygen`).<sup>1</sup>

Yes, that will be a pain, because you'll have to re-register your public key with a bunch of stuff.  But there's really no secure alternative.

---

<sub>1. And then figure out how you possibly ended up adding your key to a repo in the first place!</sub>

Comment: Deleting the private key isn't the important thing here; deleting the *public* key from everywhere it's granted access is.

Comment: I'd say there's no "you should consider" about it, that key's now toxic.  Nothing signed with it is trustworthy unless there's hard proof the signature was made before the compromise, and every bit of data accessible with it after the compromise is also now public.  If, God help you, that was your ssh key to an account you run a browser on, every stored password and card number is now toast.

Comment: @jthill - "consider" in the sense of "act as" / "assume", not as in "maybe".